# Как лучше специализировать методы в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++, методы

Написал простой пример. Есть шаблонный класс Printer, у которого метод Print. Мне нужно при определенных типах данных специализировать метод Print добавляя к нему только "шапку" для определенного типа данных (включая класс). Я решил задачу таким образом:

```
template<class T>
class Printer
{
public:
    void Print();
};

template<class T>
void Printer<T>::Print()
{
    cout << "This is method print";
}

template<>
void Printer<int>::Print()
{
    cout << "Header for int ";

    cout << "This is method print";
}

template<>
void Printer<Cottage>::Print()
{
    cout << "Header for cottage ";

    cout << "This is method print";
}
```

Однако когда я создаю реальную программу я сталкиваюсь с тем, что мне нужно постоянно копировать все поля метода по умолчанию. Таким образом кода становится реально много, а ведь мне всего лишь нужно добавить немного текста. Есть ли другой способ решить задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно добавить базовый класс:

```
template<class T>
class PrinterBase {
public:
    void Print() {
      cout << "This is method print";
    } 
};

template<class T>
class Printer: public PrinterBase<T> {
public:
    void Print() {
      PrinterBase::Print();
    }
};

template<>
void Printer<int>::Print() {
    cout << "Header for int ";
    PrinterBase::Print();
}
```

Или просто перенести реализацию в отдельный метод:

```
template<class T>
class Printer: public PrinterBase<T> {
public:
    void Print() {
      PrinterBase::doPrint();
    }
private:
    void doPrint() {
      cout << "This is method print";
    } 
};

template<>
void Printer<int>::Print() {
    cout << "Header for int ";
    doPrint();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный вами пример  позволяет даже не определять специализации.  Можно определить шаблон и еще одну функцию(если вам нужно), которая будет вызвана, если тип не тот и не другой:

```
void print(){
    //добавить код
    cout << " template parameter.\n";
}
template<class T>
void Printer<T>::Print()
{
    cout << "Header for ";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        cout << "int ";
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Cottage>)
        cout << "cottage ";
    else
        print();
    cout << "This is method print. ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Из вопроса явно не видна необходимость именно в шаблонных классах, поэтому вполне можно обойтись и без них с помощью обычного наследования и виртуальных функций:

```
#include <iostream>

class Printer {
public:
    void Print() { PrintHeader(); std::cout << "This is method print"; }
protected:
    virtual void PrintHeader() = 0;
};

class PrinterInt : public Printer {
    void PrintHeader() override { std::cout << "Header for int "; }
};

class PrinterCottage : public Printer {
    void PrintHeader() override { std::cout << "Header for cottage "; }
};

int main() {
    Printer* p = new PrinterCottage();
    p->Print();
}
```

Видно, что в этом решении достаточно только реализовать один единственный метод печати заголовка в производном классе, минимизировав дублирование кода или его смешивание в кучу для несвязных типов.

Если всё же шаблон необходим, то можно легко сделать базовый класс таковым, но это усложнит хранение экземпляров разных классов, т.к. между ними уже не будет иерархии с единым корнем.